# VLOOKUP error: formulaparse exception : specified named range "lookup_name" doesnt exist in current workbook

Tags: java, apache-poi, vlookup

I was trying to write a formula to excel using apache.
But i am getting FormulaParse Exception.

Vlookup formula:
=VLOOKUP(all_tab_columns_CIM.U11:BG25,all_tab_columns_CAM.U11:BK25,1)

My code

```
for(int i=1;i<=1;i++)
      {
          cell = row.createCell(i-1);
          cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA);           
          String s="VLOOKUP("+PageInstances.sheetName+"_CIM" + "'!$U$11:$BG$25,'"+PageInstances.sheetName+"_CAM"+"'!$U$11:$BG$25,'"+"1);";                  
          cell.setCellFormula(s);
      }
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing a `'` after the `VLOOKUP(`

Comment: Can you please give me the String s with a ' after VLOOKUP(

Comment: Tried with String s="VLOOKUP('"+PageInstances.sheetName+"_CIM."+ "'!$U$11:$BG$25,'"+PageInstances.sheetName+"_CAM."+"'!$U$11:$BG$25,1,TRUE)";   ----> But the result is not proper as expected.

Comment: I can not see clairvoyance... if the result is not as expected you need to state what the result is, what you expect and provide the input

Comment: Let us consider
String s="VLOOKUP('$"+PageInstances.sheetName+"_CIM."+ "'!$A$1:$BG$25,'$"+PageInstances.sheetName+"_CAM."+"'!$A$1:$BG$25,1)";
So now it will initially compare A1 cell in sheet1 and A1 cell in sheet2.
If that matches, it will print value in A1 cell in sheet3.
if that doesn't match, then it will print N/A
But with the above string, it was printing ?NAME

Comment: Tried with this manually in excel and it was fine
=VLOOKUP(all_tab_columns_CIM.A1:BG25,all_tab_columns_CAM.A1:BK25,1)

Comment: `#NAME` error indicates a function with wrong names/arguments

Comment: I actually doubt that `=VLOOKUP(all_tab_columns_CIM.A1:BG25,all_tab_columns_CAM.A1:BK25,1)` even works in excel. AFAIK you reference sheets like this: `=<sheetName>!<cellReference>`

Comment: all_tab_columns_CIM -->This is a sheet1, all_tab_columns_CAM -->This is sheet2.
so something similar is 
=VLOOKUP(sheet1.A1:BG25,sheet2.A1:BK25,1)
This was working fine in excel manually

Comment: Which excel do you use? In 2016 this doesn't work. 2016 thinks `sheet1.A1` is sheet1, while it should be only `sheet1`. Try to replace the `.` in `sheet1.A1` with `!`